# xmlnodeconverter can only convert json that begins with an object

Tags: c#, json

Estoy intentando convertir un archivo JSON a XML con JsonConverter en C#. No recibo ningun error sin embargo solo me crea el archivo XML pero vacio.

string sRuta;
string sXML;

```
 sRuta = sRutaArchivo + sNombreArchivo + ".json";

 m_sArchivo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objObjeto, Formatting.Indented);

 sRuta = sRutaArchivo + sNombreArchivo + ".xml";

 sXML= JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{\"root\":" + m_sArchivo + "}", 
 "root").ToString();

File.WriteAllText(sRuta, sXML);
```

Como dije antes el codigo no me devuelve ningun error pero cuando abro el archivo xml este seencuentra vacio. El json que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
[
  {
    "CartaDePorte": {
      "FechaEmision": "2018-09-11T00:00:00",
      "NroComprobante": "000571692949 ",
      "Cereal": {
        "Codigo": 3,
        "Descripcion": "ARVEJA",
        "CodOncca": 47
      },
      "Destino": "",
      "KilosNetos": 30240.0,
      "KBSL": 30240.0,
    }
  },

  {
    "CartaDePorte": {
      "FechaEmision": "2018-11-13T00:00:00",
      "NroComprobante": "000572393892 ",
      "Cereal": {
        "Codigo": 3,
        "Descripcion": "ARVEJA",
        "CodOncca": 47
      },
      "Destino": "",
      "KilosNetos": 30020.0,
      "KBSL": 30020.0,
    }
  },

  {
    "CartaDePorte": {
      "FechaEmision": "2018-11-13T00:00:00",
      "NroComprobante": "000572398454 ",
      "Cereal": {
        "Codigo": 3,
        "Descripcion": "ARVEJA",
        "CodOncca": 47
      },
      "Destino": "",
      "KilosNetos": 31540.0,
      "KBSL": 31540.0,
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

El método `DeserializeXmlNode` devuelve un objeto `XmlDocument`, el error está al llamar `ToString` sobre este objeto.  Este método no se comporta como piensas, en este caso te devolverá el string `"System.Xml.XmlDocument"` que es el nombre de la clase, no el cuerpo del XML que quieres.  Cambia la llamada de `ToString()` a la propiedad `OuterXml`

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(...).OuterXml;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes comas luego de los campos **"KBSL": ######,** por lo que el convertidor no podrá hacer la conversión porque luego de esa coma está esperando por otro campo en el objeto json el cual no es encontrado.

Comment: Si, tenes razon, pero en realidad recorte el json para publicarlo aqui y me quedo esa coma. Pero el original no tiene ese error.